# General Algebra Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

Are there any websites that provide online help related to studying algebra. Because I am really confused about it. If someone has used some website with great results, then do let me know. It will be very helpful. 
A website that offers complete courses on different math subjects.

Comment: Is this question really so bad/off topic that it promptly got a downvote without a request for further clarification?

Comment: Well I didn't exactly found the right tag :/

Comment: I would never downvote such a question, yet I find it a very, very odd question in a site designed to help people with mathematics...

Comment: I suggest [this](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: No I was asking about some site that gives you practice questions etc.

Comment: @user87665 The *reference-request* tag isn't supposed to be used by itself, but rather in conjunction with other tags like *abstract algebra*, *calculus*, etc. Please retag the question.

Comment: @GIt Gud thanks for the clarification.

Comment: (1) http://www.mathsisfun.com/ (2) http://www.purplemath.com/ (3) Puzzles--> http://www.cut-the-knot.org/

Comment: I think the problem here is that the question is too broad. What kind of algebra are you asking about? Elementary (high school level) algebra? This is what the tag algebra-precalculus suggests, but maybe you meant undergrad level abstract algebra, or something else? You should include this information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of recommendations that I use in my teaching (and recommend):

[Math.com Math Practice](http://www.math.com/students/practice.html) - this site has several links to many mathematical topics, including Algebra and Pre-Algebra, it may be a bit simple, but that is always good as a refresher.  In a similar way is [Cool Math Algebra Crunchers](http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/algebra-practice-problems.html).

[Analyze Maths](http://www.analyzemath.com/algebra.html), with a multitude of questions and answers of many aspects of algebra.

[Algebra Help](http://www.algebrahelp.com/worksheets/), this website has many exercises also, progressing through stages of understanding from basic functions to more complex.

I hope these help.

Answer (score 2):

I learned a lot from [Khanacademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra), it is very good.

Comment: but you don't get to solve lots of practice questions.

Comment: @user87665 there are plenty of practice problems, click on a topic (one of the videos from the link) and there is a button below the title which says "Practice this topic". For example, here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/conic-sections

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Omega sure no problem, happy to help